# C++ typedef function pointer with template

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef, glm-math

I'm trying to typedef a function with templates for wrapping goal

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

typedef glm::tmat4x4<float, glm::highp> (*RotateFunc)(const glm::tmat4x4<float, glm::highp>, float, glm::tvec3<float, glm::highp> const);
RotateFunc viRotate = glm::rotate<float, glm::highp>; //error line
```

However, it's hitting the error:

> 'initializing': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'RotateFunc'

Here is the raw function definition:

```
template <typename T, precision P>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tmat4x4<T, P> rotate
(
    tmat4x4<T, P> const & m,
    T angle,
    tvec3<T, P> const & v
)
```

I've tried the macro to rename this method, but as it can't be applied across namespace, and for consistence goal...

thanks for @songyuanyao point out that i miss the &, i've fixed it but currently i hit a new link error it calls the struct has already defined. any help?

```
namespace violet 
{
    typedef glm::vec3 Vector3;
    typedef glm::mat4 Matrix4x4;
    typedef Matrix4x4(*RotateFunc)(Matrix4x4 const &, float, Vector3 const &);
    RotateFunc viRotate = glm::rotate<float, glm::highp>;
}
```

and the link error:
Error   LNK2005 "struct glm::tmat4x4 (__cdecl* violet::viRotate)(struct glm::tmat4x4 const &,float,struct glm::tvec3 const &)" (?viRotate@violet@@3P6A?AU?$tmat4x4@M$0A@@glm@@ABU23@MABU?$tvec3@M$0A@@3@@ZA) already defined in Entrance.obj OpenGL  E:\Engine\OpenGL\OpenGL\ImageImporter.obj   1

Comment: It seems the parameter type doesn't match? `const glm::tmat4x4<float, glm::highp>` vs `tmat4x4<T, P> const &`. Note the `&`.

Comment: @songyuanyao same problem with the `tvec3` parameter, too (`glm::tvec3<float, glm::highp> const` vs `tvec3<T, P> const &`)

Comment: And depending on what `GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER` expands to, you may need some (implementation-defined) qualification on `RotateFunc`

Comment: @Caleth GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER expands to "inline" on current context, i can not set this to the function-pointer and i've try directly delete the glm::rotate qualification, but still get the said link issue

Comment: Are you doing this in a header file? The linker error is informing you that multiple translation units have a definition of the same object. You can declare `extern RotateFunc viRotate` in the header, and move `RotateFunc violet::viRotate = glm::rotate<float, glm::highp>;` to an implementation file

Comment: @Caleth thanks for help, i did do this in a header fie, it is now working, but i wonder if i have done it in a good way, since i can not put the qualifier **GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER**, will i get some cross platform issue if the qualifier changed? and is it better to use macro for rename a extern function?